# Youtube Player API Samples

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I was trying the following code from the samples given on developers.google.com/*

```
<script>
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'yZxrao3zou4',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    </script>
```

The code works perfectly when I have nothing else on my web page, but when I try to merge it with my project it doesn't seem to work.

I am guessing the problem is with the following lines:

```
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Can someone tell me what does the above two lines do, especially the [0] part?

My code is pretty much the same except that instead of the script tag I have the code inside a function, which takes in a argument for the videoId.

EDIT:
My code is as follows:

```
<script>
    // I have a input area, where the user can enter the movie name. When the user submits the movie name, I capture the val and pass it to the youtube().
    function youtube(movie_name) {
        var videoId;
        $.ajax({
            url:"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+movie_name+"&type=video&key=my_key",
            success: function (response) {
                videoId = response.items[0].id.videoId;
                findMovieById(videoId);
            }
        });

    }

    function findMovieById(videoID) {

        $("#player").css('display', 'inline-block');
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: ""+videoID,
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            alert('Player Ready');
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }
        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('script') returns the array of all script element on your html, and this code inserts the iframe_api before your first scripting tag (0th element of script tag array). can you show your merged code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the sample code is that it is much more consistent when you load the YouTube iFrame library code *after* the rest of the page has loaded; hence the sample code demonstrates that you put an inline  at the bottom of the page, and within that, you traverse the DOM, find a place where you can insert another  tag, and do so dynamically (the [0] just says 'the first entry in the array of all elements of name  in the document).

The logic here is that, when the iFrame library loads, it will call the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`. But since the library loads asynchronously, it's best to load it this way to ensure that anything else that your API hooks might depend on (the element in the DOM you're binding to, for example) already exists.

Also note that, because the loaded library will always call the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function, it *MUST* be defined outside any other function. Otherwise it isn't callable. That could be why nesting it inside your code somewhere isn't working.

Feel free to post some of your merged code for more detailed help.

Comment: It seems putting onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() out of the body of the other function worked. However, I have another problem. I am being able to play the video as per the videoId received by findMovieById() only once. Once I change the videoId by entering a different movie name in the input area, the videoId gets updated, but the player doesn't get updated to show this change. It seems I need to add some functionality to the onPlayerStateChange(event). Can you suggest me what I can do in this function, to make the player play the updated movie video

Comment: You could set up a conditional statement where, if the player has already been created, it instead just loads the new video. You'll also want to move the loading of the iFrame library outside of any function you are calling, to avoid it being loaded multiple times (and to avoid onYouTubeIFrameAPIReady being called multiple times). Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/26bAx/5/